# prevent $filter to increase the day when input day exceeds the maximum day in a month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

I am new to angular. I am working on a date and  using $filter for filtering date value . The problem with date filter in angularjs is that it adds days to date input in case the number of day exceeds the maximum day for the given month . If i enter 2015-02-31 in input  , the filter result shows 2015-03-03 . How can i use $filter and prevent increase of day to my date value ? Can you give me some suggestion? I am using filter in this way.

```
 <p>Selected date 1 is: <strong>{{mydate |date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</strong></p>
```

Here is my code in  [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FDigEjyMYm5SVYnQyZGp).

Comment: The filter doesn't add anything. `mydate` has that value in the first place. Blame the date picker.

Comment: If i enter 2015-02-31 in input manually (as there is no way i can get 2015-02-31 with datepicker)  , it has nothing to do with  datepicker .  .

Comment: And who do you think converts the string into a date?

Comment: date filter convert string to date format .  In my updated plunkr i add independent input and use date  filter to display it . http://plnkr.co/edit/FDigEjyMYm5SVYnQyZGp .

Comment: @Jigs I think `zeroflagL` may be right. Removing the date filter it still does exactly the same?

Comment: @ste2425 sorry , i didn't get you .

Comment: @Jigs well you have a date controll producing a date. Then your using the date filter ` |date:'yyyy-MM-dd'` to print that date out in the specified format? Well removing that filter so its just `<p>Selected date 1 is: <strong>{{mydate}}</strong></p>` prints out the date in its entirety but it still increases the date. This was with your second plunker. So it can't be the filter on that date as its still behaving the same.

Comment: If `mydate` is not already an instance of `Date`, then the date filter would convert it into one. In either case, the problem is with `Date`, not the filter itself. Try `new Date ('2015-02-31')` to see what I mean. Since you use a date picker anyway the simplest solution is to forbid manual input. Otherwise you have to validate the input.

Comment: oh. The actual problem is with javascript Date Object . I get it . Thanks .